# How do I append a string to an array of strings within a loop in C?

Tags: c, c99

I'm struggling to see how I can append a string to an array of strings, given that the value being added to each time (therefore the value the pointer points to is changing). I'm expecting `array` to be in the format `{"hello, "helloo", ...}` but I can't get this to work. What changes can I make so that `array` stores this correctly?

```
int size = 10;
char *string = "hello";
char c = "o";
char *array[size];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    strcat(string, c);
    array[i] = string;
}
```

Comment: This shouldn't even compile, `char c = "o";` and `strcat(string, c);` are both invalid

Comment: First thing first, you need to realize that after the loop *all* elements of the array are pointing to the *same* string, because all you have is a single string. In order to have `size` different strings, you need `size` strings. Not just `size` pointers to strings.

Comment: @UnholySheep this is just a minimum reproducible example to support my question, my main problem is that I'm not sure how I can find a way to append strings to an array of string within a loop

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I see, but consider the case that in the program, the value of `string` has to change every loop, how can I find a way to store this in `array`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops... there are tons of errors here!

Let us go back to the basics: C language has no notion of what a string could be. At the language level you only have the (single) character type: `char`. At the library level, a string is representented by a null terminated character array.

So to be able to add a character to a string, you must have an array of the correct dimension. BTW, a litteral like `"hello"` is a const character array: the programmer cannot change anything to it.

So here you want to be able to add 1 to 10 character to "hello", so you need a 16 character array: 5 for hello, 10 for the additional `o` and 1 for the null. But that is not all, `array` is just an array of pointers. If all elements of `array` point to the same string to which you add characters, at the end they will all have the very same value! You must have each element of the array to point to a different character array. Assuming that `strdup` is available you could write:

```
int size = 10;
char string[16] = "hello";  // build an array of size 16 initialized to "hello"
const char *c = "o";        // beware a string literal IS const
char *array[size];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    strcat(string, c);
    array[i] = strdup(string);  // build a dynamic copy
}
```

When you will no longer need `array` you should free all strings allocated with `strdup`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    free(array[i]);
}
```

BTW, `strdup` is only in the standard C library since C23, it previously was just a POSIX extension. If is in not available on your system you can roll you own:

```
char *strdup(const char *src) {
    char *dest = malloc(1 + strlen(src));
    strcpy(dest, src);
    return dest;
}
```

---

Alternatively you could avoid dynamic allocation by using a true 2D array:

```
int size = 10;
char string[16] = "hello";  // build an array of size 16 initialized to "hello"
const char *c = "o";        // beware a string literal IS const
char *array[size][16];      // this is an array of 10 strings of size 16

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    strcat(string, c);
    strcpy(array[i], string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless the string is dynamically allocated, the size needs to be pre determined. Also, `char str_name[size]` is how a string is defined.

```c
int size = 10;
char string[size + 5] = "hello";
char c[2] = "o";
char* array[size];

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    array[i] = string;
    strcat(string, c);
}
```